# Obs-Studio :if you are using NVENC or AMD encoders, make sure your video drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have already OBS-studio which installed by ubuntu software app and working fine, but i have uninstalled it for virtual cam and running depfake tech like [this](https://github.com/alew3/faceit_live3) GitHub project.

Now i have tried to install it by `sudo pat install obs-studio`, and i have this eroro when i am trying to record video by it:

`if you are using NVENC or AMD encoders, make sure your video drivers` 
[image]

and my driver are like this:

```
o@sosa:~/Downloads/trash$ /usr/bin/nvidia-smi

Tue Sep 15 17:54:47 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 920MX       Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   61C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    516MiB /  2004MiB |     89%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1409      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 67MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2063      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                229MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2689      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              170MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3308      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3407      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4090      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6272      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18214      G   obs                                27MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18455      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Ubuntu version is:

```
so@sosa:~/Downloads/trash$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: @ajinzrathod, no, but I am using this video record setting : https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8L2Q.png